# I need to run Shell Script using django in side a Docker container

Tags: python, django, shell, docker

```
my shell file
```

```
    #!/bin/bash

    echo "Success"

    exit 1
```

I called the above file using following command.
python file

```
     subprocess.call(["bash", "scripts/test.sh"], shell=True)
```

This works fine when running without the Docker container. But it shows an error when running inside the container.

error:

```
python_1         | scripts/test.sh: line 1: bash: not found
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are we supposed to guess the error?

Comment: Please add the error message that you are getting.

Comment: I have added the error.

Comment: your container doesn't have bash, or it's not available from the current directory. Try using `/bin/bash` (or better, use `which bash` to figure out where bash is located).

Comment: @thebjorn thank you. The problem was container doesn't have a bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a base image that doesn't have bash installed. For example, Alpine doesn't have bash installed by default.

I would suggest against using Alpine (https://pythonspeed.com/articles/alpine-docker-python/) but if you are using it you can install bash by doing:

```
RUN apk add --update-cache bash
```

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Morning!

Are you sure that you are sharing that file in the container?

The command you use should specify what folder are you sharing between the container and the main system.

[This may help](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-share-data-between-the-docker-container-and-the-host)

Comment: Yes, I am sure.